# Help me understand "Go down a treat"

Tags: idioms, british-english

If for example I am describing how good was my last dinner to someone, can I say:

- it was delicious it went down a treat!

Or simply:

- it was a treat

What is the difference if there is any?
Thank you

Comment: Did you look up [the meaning of *go down a treat*](http://grammarist.com/spelling/go-down-a-treat/) and [the meaning of *treat*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/treat)?  What do you think the difference is?

Comment: When treat is use as a noun, it refers to something really good. Most of the time for food I guess. So for me: "it was a treat" is perfectly fine.
However, I'd know the difference With "Go down a treat"

Answer (score 3):

If something

> goes down a treat *(usually BrE)*

it means an event or occassion was very enjoyable and the enjoyability is a metaphoric comparison to the food use of

> treats

A food "treat" is something which is enjoyed, sometimes as a reward e.g. "doggy treats", may or may not be expected, and is usually considered as something "special".  Saying

> It was a treat.

May or may not have the same general meaning as your original phrase.

> For the kids, it was a real *treat* to meet Santa Claus, but some of them were scared.

in this case "treat" has the meaning of "special", but it may not "have gone down a treat".